# internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory could not find error with jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I am using Spring 4.3 and JPA to my project. I used java configuration to configure Hibernate instead of XMl configuration. But when I am compiling below error message is received. Please direct me to resolve this problem.

**Following is the stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not find the type for bean named org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.getBeanClass(SpringBeanProcessor.java:456)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.processBean(SpringBeanProcessor.java:280)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpringBeanProcessor.java:258)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(SpringContextLoaderListener.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:666)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:217)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**JPA configuration class**

```
`@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application/core-application.properties" })
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws NamingException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.dak.school.model" });
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties());
        return factoryBean;
    }

    /*
    * Provider specific adapter.
    */
    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    /*
     * Here you can specify any provider specific properties.
     */
    private Properties jpaProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        // properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return txManager;
    }
} `
```

**Application properties file**

```
> jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver jdbc.url =
> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school_suit jdbc.username = root
> jdbc.password = admin123fg hibernate.dialect =
> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
> hibernate.show_sql = true hibernate.format_sql = true
```

**Service implementation class**

```
@Service
//@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private  UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(final User user) {

        userDao.create(user);

    }
}
```

**Dao implementation class**

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl extends DaoImpl<User,Long> implements UserDao {

}
```

**Abstract Daoimpl class**

```
public abstract class DaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> implements IDao<T, PK> {

  /* Persistence Entity class type. */
  protected Class<T> entityClass;

  /* Entity manager to perform DAO operations. */
  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  /**
   * Constructor
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public DaoImpl() {

    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see com.fg.baking.core.dao.IDao#create(java.lang.Object)
   */
  public T create(T t) {

    this.entityManager.persist(t);
    return t;
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see com.fg.baking.core.dao.IDao#read(java.io.Serializable)
   */
  public T read(PK id) {

    return this.entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see com.fg.baking.core.dao.IDao#update(java.lang.Object)
   */
  public T update(T t) {

    return this.entityManager.merge(t);
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see com.fg.baking.core.dao.IDao#delete(java.lang.Object)
   */
  public void delete(T t) {

    t = this.entityManager.merge(t);
    this.entityManager.remove(t);
  }


  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * 
   * @see com.yummy.platform.spring.dao.BaseDao#findAll()
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<T> findAll() {

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " c");
    return (List<T>) query.getResultList();
  }


}
```

**Dependency details**

```
 <spring.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <taglib.standard.version>1.1.2</taglib.standard.version>
        <!--<servlet.api.version>3.0.1</servlet.api.version>-->
        <servlet.api.version>3.1.0</servlet.api.version>
        <servlet.api.jsp.version>2.3.1</servlet.api.jsp.version>
        <resteasy.version>3.0.11.Final</resteasy.version>

        <apache.commnos.beanutil.version>1.9.0</apache.commnos.beanutil.version>
        <apache.commnos.codec.version>1.9</apache.commnos.codec.version>
        <commons.collections.version>3.2.1</commons.collections.version>
        <commons-digester.version>3.2</commons-digester.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.3</commons-logging.version>
        <commons-dbcp.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp.version>
        <commons-lang.version>2.4</commons-lang.version>

        <mysql.connector.version>6.0.5</mysql.connector.version>
        <hibernate.core.version>5.2.9.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <javax.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</javax.validation.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error while migrating an existing spring application(with XML configurations) to springboot:

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

The bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined and overriding is dis
abled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

And I fixed this by removing couple of duplicate "`<tx:`" configurations from my old xml.
Initially I had added that property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` which will simply hide that error from console. But that is not fixing the underlying issue. Hence, removal of duplicate configuration fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `transactionManager` bean with this:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txManager;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But error is still there. Problem is txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()); methos can not apply entityManagerFactory(). It required EntityManagerFactory object.

Comment: I have updated my answer . using `getObject()` method of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` we can get `entityManager` object

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an similar issue as https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-1241.  I resolve my issue by upgrading RESTEasy from 3.0.10.Final to 3.0.19.Final.